# Chebyshev Theorm for discrete Variable proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i am an engineering student currently taking a class from a math professor. this far from my expertise and I hoped other than I got the answer to my questions, perhaps I got enlighten by it.

Are there any source I could learn things related to proving Chebyshev Theorm for discrete variables?

It would be great if there's a source I could learn beside the answer to my question.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Googling "Chebyshev's inequality"?

Comment: i have but having a hard time determining which one is actually what I need

Comment: i think the Chebyshev's inequality is far from what my professor want. i just want to prove the interval of a certain probability

Comment: http://www.dim.uchile.cl/~mkiwi/ma34a/libro/ch8.pdf  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: something about 1 - (1/k^2)
and then interval